# Using class member functions without initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

Why is it possible to use class member functions on an uninitialized object (at least I believe it's uninitialized). The following runs without error:

```c
// A.h
class A {
 public:
  explicit A(int n) : n_(n) {};
  ~A() {};
  int foo() {
    return n_;
  };
  int bar(int i) {
    return i;
  };
 private:
  int n_;
};
```

with

```c
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  A *myClass;
  std::cout << myClass->bar(5) << "\n";
}
```

Now, certainly attempting `myClass->foo();`fails, but why can we even use `bar()` when all we've declared is that a pointer to `A` exists, and is called `myClass`? Is this acceptable coding style/is there ever a reason to use this approach?

Comment: Say hello to undefined behavior.

Comment: I you want to be able to call a function associated with a class but is not a member function use static calls.

Comment: It's not actually an uninitialized object.  There is no object of type `A` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can we even use `bar()` when all we've declared is that a pointer to `A` exists, and is called `myClass`?

Because, in general, it's impossible for the compiler to tell whether a pointer will be valid at runtime; so it isn't required to diagnose this error. However, in this case, a decent compiler should be able to issue a warning, as long as you're not building with warnings disabled.

> Is this acceptable coding style/is there ever a reason to use this approach?

Absolutely not. Dereferencing an invalid pointer gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't know if the block of memory where myClass is pointing to is an initialized object, it have right syntax, but undefined behavior, however if want to prevent, you should use -Wall or a similar compiler option (depends on your compiler) and it will warn you about the uninitialized pointer.